# Update the data in datatable instead of reload whole page in codeigneator

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter

When I insert or update the data using modal form of bootstrap and ajax It's reload the whole page. Instead of reload whole page only refresh the data table.

This is My Script of ajax:-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#tbl_member').dataTable({
                 "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "aoColumnDefs": [
                    {"bSortable": false, "aTargets": [0,2]}
                ]
            });
    });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.editTech').on('click',function()
    {
            var id = $(this).data('id');
            $.ajax({
                    url      : "<?php echo  base_url(); ?>Technology/loadEditTech",
                    type     : "POST",
                    data:{"id":id},
                    success  : function(data)
                    {
                            $('#techModal .modal-content').html(data);  
                            techValidateEdit();
                            $('#techModal').modal('show');  
                    },
                    error: function()
                    {
                        alert("failure");
                    }
            });
    });
    function techValidateEdit()
    {
            $('#frmTech').validate({
                rules:{},
                submitHandler:function()
                {
                        $.ajax({
                        url      : "<?php echo base_url(); ?>Technology/manage_technology",
                        type     : "POST",
                        data     : $('#frmTech').serialize(),
                        success  : function(data)
                        {
                                $('#techModal').modal('hide');  
                                window.location.reload();

                        },
                        error: function()
                        {
                            alert('error');
                        }
                    });
                 }
            });  
    }
    </script>
```

Here The scenario is when i click on add button open the modal form and add some data after click on save button from modal form it's reload the page. But I want reload only data table instead of reload whole page.

I am using version 1.9.4 of datatable.

Comment: This is very broad, and too much code - and there are explicit "reload" instructions in the success events. You'd likely simply have to get rid of those

Comment: Ya but insetad Of that window.reload only refresh the data table. So what kind of function i use there?

Comment: It appears you can reload a data table using http://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload() (provided your data source returns JSON data)

Comment: I don't understand how to replace with my code. The link which u provide that i saw but can't understand that how to apply it with my code

Comment: can u please edit it in this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this tutorial Here is your answer: http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-insert-and-view-data-without-refreshing-page-using-ajax-and-jquery-in-codeigniter/
 Because it is not possible to write down the full code here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I actually have a very nice piece of code to do this exact thing too!

I generate my datatable with some queries from CI which get each column name for me so it will auto generate the headers for me, my Jquery looks like :

```
$("td").click(function(e){

    var $oldvalue = $(this);
    $oldvalue = $oldvalue.html();
    var $id =$(this).parent().data('id');
    $('td[contenteditable]').keydown(function(e) {
        // trap the return key being pressed
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $value = $(this);
            var $field =  $("table thead tr th").eq($value.index());
            $valuenew = $value.html();
            $field = $field.html();

            $.post( "/admin/database/ajax/edit", { id: $id,newvalue: $valuenew, field: $field , table : "users"} );
        }
    });
});
```

My controller handles the request as follow:

```
function ajaxEdit(){
    $array = array($this->input->post("field") => $this->input->post("newvalue"));
    $this->general_model->updateRow($this->input->post("table"), 'id', $this->input->post("id"), $array);
}
```

My model looks as follow:

```
public function updateRow($table, $field, $id, $array = false){

    if($array != false){
        $array = $array;
    } else {
        $array = $this->cleanPostArray();   // Let the POST be cleaned / scanned
    }

    $this->db->where($field, $id);
    $this->db->update($table, $array);

    return 1;   // 1 = success
}

public function cleanPostArray(){

    $POSTarray = $this->input->post();
    $array = array();

    foreach($POSTarray as $key => $val):

        if($key == "password"){
            // Value needs to be salted / hashed!
            if($val != ""){
                $val = YourEncryptionForPW;
                $array[$key] = $val;
            }
        }else {
            $array[$key] = $val;
        }

    endforeach;

    return $array;
}
```

Comment: Is there any other method or function which i replace in my code in place of window.location.reload().

Comment: Translation: "write some code for me". That's not how this place works, Kim.

Comment: try  this http://w3code.in/2015/09/how-to-insert-and-view-data-without-refreshing-page-using-ajax-and-jquery-in-codeigniter

Comment: @Rakesh this link is not work for me.. It's not reload the datatable.

Comment: Please make sure you will use button to submit or update the data.(<input type="button">) don't use <input type="submit">

Comment: currently window.location.reload() works but instead of that only data table should reload

Comment: Remove  window.location.reload() that is not required in your case.You can alert a message of data success there.

Comment: No still it's not update the datatable. Data added successfully but after alert It's not reflect in datatable

Comment: This is not possible to refresh the data table only. you need to make the html of the inserted data and then append it in youe datatable

Comment: Sure But this is not possible to write down the full code here. I will let you know  when I will update anywhere in my blog today onword

Comment: Here is your answer: http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-edit-delete-and-update-data-without-refreshing-page-in-codeigniter/

Comment: Thank You very much @rakesh.. Helpfull answer

Comment: You are most welcome. Please do not forget to share with your friend it might help them too.

Comment: Ya sure will definitely share with friedns

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91857/discussion-between-kim-jones-and-rakesh).